# Is it possible to serve a theme from outside the web root?

Tags: 7, files

We have a need to keep a proprietary theme in a directory that isn't readable or writable by a client.

At the same time, the client needs to be able to do standard Drupal updates (ie, they will have full control of the web root of the Drupal installation, but nothing above that).

What's the easiest/best way to accomplish this, assuming it's possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

set for the `DocumentRoot` for your Drupal site, you can put the proprietary theme anywhere you want as long as you create a symlink to it somewhere Drupal searches for themes (eg, sites/all/themes).

Just keep in mind that Apache needs to be able to read it.  Whether the client can read it directly is a permission issue, but if Apache can read it a savy client can get it via custom PHP.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can never completely keep the CSS, JavaScript, images and HTML output to yourself, because it is sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, MPD. A symlink seems sensible. Appreciate the warning about the accessing via PHP as well. I'll let you know what way we go on this.

Comment: @marcvangend, that's a good point and something we're willing to live with. The theme itself we do need to keep as protected as possible.